# Install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on old Samsung r519

Tags: hard-drive, uefi, windows-7, boot-repair

I found a Samsung r519 from 2009 laying unused in my house and decided to wipe Windows 7 from it & install Ubuntu 18.04 from live usb.
The problem is, when the installation is finished and I try to turn the device on, it won't boot! There's a blank screen interface instead. 
This machine uses EFI as booting system, yet it doesn't have a UEFI interface but a BIOS one; I tried wiping the HDD several times and reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch, yet nothing changed.

This is the log file I obtained running Boot Repair from a live USB, hope it is useful to solve the problem...

[bootinfo.text](https://mega.nz/#!HKRUQYJQ!5n0OvMSR-V10dWTjGCXHJaCL4d4q0blPzVoPKp3B7Pw)